# SQL query is taking too long to insert

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, database-administration

I am trying to insert data into P_TABLE which is taking lot of time ~5-6 hrs to insert .Its a simple insert joining with big tables .Is there any way to reduce the timing? its a truncate and load process

I have provided the necessary information including Explain.

```
P_TABLE -- PARTITION ON TEAM
WH_TAB --- Total count = 2222000000
UNIQUE INDEX ON EX_ID,PROD_CD,CAM_CD,SEG_CD,LIST_CD,MAIL_DT
PARTITION BY RANGE (MAIL_DT) 

REF_TAB--Total count= 240000000 
ACT_TAB --Total count =  31239890

ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
INSERT /*+ append */ INTO P_TABLE
(
    V_CODE,
    CST_ID,
    EX_ID,
    PROD_CD,
    CAM_CD,
    SEG_CD,
    LIST_CD,
    MAIL_DT
)
SELECT
'ABC',
COALESCE(REF.CST_ID, WH.CST_ID),
WH.EX_ID,
PROD_CD,
CAM_CD,
SEG_CD,
LIST_CD,
F.TEAM,
FROM WH_TAB WH
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT  EX_ID, CST_ID, ACCT_ID, row_number() over(partition by EX_ID order by CST_ID asc) RN
FROM REF_TAB
) REF
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_TAB F
on F.CST_ID=REF.CST_ID
ON REF.RN=1 AND REF.EX_ID=WH.EX_ID
WHERE TRUNC(MAIL_DT) >= add_months(TRUNC(sysdate),-13)
AND WH.CAM_CD NOT LIKE 'ORD%';


COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you run the select part of the statement without the insert to establish whether the slow part is the query or the insert.

It's likely that it's the select that's the problem, so the table structure, including indexes and explain output are really needed to say much more.

Comment: only index created in WH_TAB as I mentioned in the top of the query with other table details as well including total rows in each table.